# Weird black pixels in the corners of CProgressCtrl controls

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, mfc, progress-bar

I have an MFC dialog (actual a dialog bar with in a dialog) that contains a progress bar with these strange black pixels in the corner.  I have tried the following to remove them:

- Change most of the border type styles and the transparent style of the control.
- Override the OnEraseBkgnd in a class derived a CProgressCtrl.
- Setting the background color of the control by PBM_SETBKCOLOR.

I have yet to find a way to remove these black pixel.

Here is an example of what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: I don't know how to reverse-engineer code from a screenshot.  Post a minimum sample project that exhibits this problem to a file sharing service.

Comment: The progress control is the normal one provided by the dialog resource.  The dialogs' OnEraseBackground is as follows:
`CRect rc; GetClientRect(rc);`
`if (!m_brBackground.GetSafeHandle()){`
`CBrush brBack;`
`brBack.CreateSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);`
`pDC->FillRect(rc, &brBack);`
`}else{`
`pDC->FillRect(rc, &m_brBackground);`
`}`

Comment: Also, to explain the OnEraseBackground; the m_brBackground member is a brush created from a bitmap that is loaded from the programs resources.  It is passed to static controls only in OnCtlColor, which is a bit too big for the comment box :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I have found the issue.  When the progress bar performs its painting it was sending an WM_ERASEBKGND message to the dialog to get the background with which it would paint.  Some how the DC brush origin was being messed up.  Using the following code at the start of the function seems to have fixed the issue with no ill effects.

```
CRect rcClip;
pDC->GetClipBox(rcClip);
pDC->SetBrushOrg(-rcClip.left, -rcClip.top);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this occur when using ActiveX controls inside control containers that don't have a a window or proper Device Contexts (The VB6 frame control is one of these) but I'm not sure if the same problem applies to MFC windows and controls though.

Try making the control parent a normal static window.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense.  Are you talking about windowless ActiveX controls?

Comment: I think so, I've reworded my answer a bit (Probably still doesn't apply in which case I'll delete it)

Comment: There is no ActiveX controls involved and the control's parent is the dialog (via the dialog template resource.)